# Opt out of `char` exemption to strict aliasing rules

Tags: c++, types, compiler-optimization, simd, strict-aliasing

If I have a simple piece of code using `uint32_t` then it can be optimised better than the same code with `uint8_t`. As far as I know this is because char has exemptions to the strict aliasing rules. Consider:

```
using T = uint32_t;

T *a;
T *b;
T *c;

void mult(int num)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < num; count++)
    {
        a[count] = b[count] * c[count];
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sW1xnTrhc

This has an inner loop in `-01` of:

```
.LBB0_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     r8d, dword ptr [rcx + 4*rdi]
        imul    r8d, dword ptr [rax + 4*rdi]
        mov     dword ptr [rdx + 4*rdi], r8d
        inc     rdi
        cmp     rsi, rdi
        jne     .LBB0_2
```

Note in this case it simply load one value, does a multiply, stores the result, and loops. This is good. However if I used `uint8_t` (https://godbolt.org/z/doM4o6ena) I get this inner loop from clang:

```
.LBB0_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rip + b] # see here
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + c] # see here
        movzx   eax, byte ptr [rax + rdx]
        mul     byte ptr [rsi + rdx]
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rip + a] # see here
        mov     byte ptr [rsi + rdx], al
        inc     rdx
        cmp     rcx, rdx
        jne     .LBB0_2
```

Note that this inner loop loads the values of `a`, `b` and `c` every single iteration. This is as I understand because the storage of the pointer for `a`, `b` and `c` may alias with what is pointed to, and so the loop must run each iteration separately, and reload the values. This gets even worse with higher optimisation levels. Using `uint16_t` and/or `uint32_t` with `-O3` the compiler does all sorts of SIMD/XMM wizardry but the `uint8_t`/`char` loop remains stubbornly simple and unoptimised.

Note I am **not** asking for ways round this using `restrict`, or avoiding global variables. Nor am I asking for ways to optimise this specific example.

What I am asking is if there is a simple 8 bit arithmetic type which I can use which can't fall into this trap.

Comment: You'd probably want to define a type in the same way as [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) but with all of the other arithmetic operators overloaded analogously as well. (Note however that `std::byte` itself is not suitable, because it also has aliasing exceptions. But that's _specifically_ for `std::byte` and wouldn't apply to a user-defined type with the same definition.)

Comment: I was curious if lack of SIMD was just due to the fact that x86's narrowest SIMD multiply is 16x16 => 16-bit (except for SSSE3 `pmaddubsw` which adds horizontal pairs of byte products), so vertical `uint8_t` multiply would have to unpack to 16-bit and repack.  That's not the only problem; without `T *local_a = a` (https://godbolt.org/z/158ar4T9c), we don't get vectorization even on AArch64 which does have `mul     v0.16b, v0.16b, v1.16b` which GCC uses when you copy the pointers to locals to work around the aliasing problem.  Or SVE with `-mcpu=cortex-a710`.

Comment: (Neither compiler makes asm to check if the current `a` to `a+num` includes `&a` or not, they just make scalar loops if the loop uses any pointer globals.)

Comment: @PeterCordes interesting point. I tried instead with addition and that still has the same issues even though `_mm_add_epi8` (aka `paddb`) exists.

Comment: And agree'd, for this particular example putting `a`, `b` and `c` into locals fixes things. But I would prefer not have to special case things to deal with weird interactions in the language if possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found too.  Like I said, I had to change the source to get it to auto-vectorize even on AArch64.  And on x86, GCC and clang will unpack and repack around `pmullw` for source they are willing to auto-vectorize.  (And yes, there are workarounds, but still upvoted because it's a good question.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with strict aliasing rules. Those are about an object of one type overlapping an object of a different type. You don't have this situation in either version of the code.

Comment: If anyone is interested, this is seen happening in the old doom code. See https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM/blob/master/linuxdoom-1.10/r_draw.c#L105. In this function (`R_DrawColumn‎`) `*dest = dc_colormap[dc_source[(frac>>FRACBITS)&127]];` reloads `dc_colormap` and `dc_source` every time. Now obviously DOOM code isn't modern or particularly recommended coding style, but it does show this issue can/does exist.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI - in this example, the `uint32_t` version reads the value of a `uint32_t *` (a.k.a `b`) and stores a `uint32_t`. The store of the `uint32_t` cannot change the value of the `uint32_t*` which represents `a`, `b` and c due to strict aliasing and so the compiler doesn't need to reload `a`, `b` or `c`. Unless there's a different name for this? With the `byte` version the store of a byte can affect the load of a `byte*` as `byte` has strict aliasing exemption, and so the compiler needs to reload the value of `a` `b` and `c` each time. If this isn't strict aliasing what is it called?

Comment: "The store of the uint32_t cannot change the value of the uint32_t* which represents a, b" That's just not true. a, b and c can all point into the same array.

Comment: You are misunderstanding. I don't care that `c[i]` is loaded each iteration. In the `byte` version the value of `c` _itself_ is reloaded. And then from this value `c[i]` is loaded each iteration of the loop. So the byte version does 5 loads per iteration (`a`, `b`, `b[i]` `c`, `c[i]`), whereas the int/short version does 2 loads per iteration (just `b[i]` and `c[i]`) as it uses the cached values of `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It is about the pointer value itself. The store of a `unsigned char` could change the pointer value, not only the object that the pointer points to, e.g. `a = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&b);` could have been done.

Comment: Ahhh that's what's going on. Strict aliasing rules are restrictions on what *you* can do, not on what the compiler can do. In particular the compiler can refuse to optimise anything it wants. It can refuse to optimise any 8-bit type, whether subject to strict aliasing rules as defined by the standard or not. GCC already does this: its own version of strict aliasing rules is more broad than the standard's, that is, it assumes that there are more valid aliasing cases than the standard allows. If you need optimisations, your only choice is to manually check *everything* you want optimised.

Comment: Strict aliasing rules identify situations where compilers would be allowed to transform code in ways that would alter its meaning if doing so would be useful to their customers, or if it wouldn't be useful to the compiler's customers but the compiler's maintainers feel like doing it anyway.  The C++ Standard is by its own terms **NOT** a specification for programs, but merely for implementations.